# Adhoc Queries filling up plan cache

Tags: sql-server-2016

I have a bloated plan cache because of Adhoc queries. 
I have SQL job that goes in and purges Adhoc plans every hour. (This process was adopted from Kimberly Tripp in regards to Plan cache bloat). 
When I look at the top 50 adhoc plans I see this (with much more content in each row) for all 50:

*Select '100', 0, ''; begin try dbcc inputbuffer(100) with no_infomsgs end try begin catch select 'RPC Event',0,'(unknown)' end catch; Select '102', 0, '';*

How can I prevent that from filling up my plan cache? BTW..
I do have optimize for ad hoc workloads on.

Thanks,
Shelz

Comment: When I run Glen Barrys query: -- Find single-use, ad-hoc and prepared queries that are bloating the plan cache  (Query 43) (Ad hoc Queries)
SELECT TOP(50) [text] AS [QueryText], cp.cacheobjtype, cp.objtype, cp.size_in_bytes/1024 AS [Plan Size in KB]
FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS cp WITH (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle) 
WHERE cp.cacheobjtype = N'Compiled Plan' 
AND cp.objtype IN (N'Adhoc', N'Prepared') 
AND cp.usecounts = 1
ORDER BY cp.size_in_bytes DESC OPTION (RECOMPILE); It tells about the ad hoc queries. I'd like to figure out  where it is coming from

Comment: When I run sp_BlitzCache here are the results: Plan Cache Information You have 5169 total plans in your cache, with 100.00% plans created in the past 24 hours, 58.00% created in the past 4 hours, and 43.00% created in the past 1 hour. Is it normal to have that much churn on the plans? Really I would like to know what the ad hoc query is?

Answer (score -2):

Following can be used to clean adhoc and prepared query plan cache . This is from [Glenn Berry - Eight Different Ways to Clear the SQL Server Plan Cache](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/eight-different-ways-to-clear-the-sql-server-plan-cache/)

```
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE ('SQL Plans')
```

It also says:

> “I would argue that running DBCC FREEPROCCACHE does not cause that much distress with a modern processor, even on a very busy OLTP system. It will cause a pretty minor CPU spike for a few seconds on most systems as the query plans get recompiled as they are executed. “

Following query can give adhoc queries in the plan cache

```
SELECT  DISTINCT 
        QCP.objtype
        ,MultipleQ.PlanCount
        ,qStat.query_hash
        ,sText.text AS QueryText
        ,size_in_bytes
        ,qStat.creation_time
FROM ( 
        SELECT query_hash,
               COUNT(query_hash) AS PlanCount
        FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats
        GROUP BY query_hash
    ) AS MultipleQ
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_query_stats qStat ON MultipleQ.query_hash = qStat.query_hash
INNER JOIN sys.dm_exec_cached_plans  QCP
    ON QCP.plan_handle = qStat.plan_handle
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qStat.sql_handle) AS sText
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qStat.plan_handle) AS qp
WHERE PlanCount > 1
AND QCP.objtype = 'Adhoc'
ORDER BY MultipleQ.PlanCount DESC
```

If you have `Query Store` you can use “Delete ad-hoc queries” as defined in 
[Monitoring performance by using the Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017#Scenarios)

Enabling optimize for adhoc workloads can be found in  [Kimberly Tripp - Plan cache and optimizing for adhoc workloads](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/plan-cache-and-optimizing-for-adhoc-workloads/)

Comment: I was trying to get this answered: When I run sp_BlitzCache here are the results: Plan Cache Information You have 5169 total plans in your cache, with 100.00% plans created in the past 24 hours, 58.00% created in the past 4 hours, and 43.00% created in the past 1 hour. Is it normal to have that much churn on the plans? Really I would like to know what the ad hoc query is? – Shellz Jan 31 '18 at 16:25